# Unable to get login details on Spring security with Angular 2 as front end and using Basic Http Authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, angular

I am using Spring as my backend and Angular 2.0.0-beta.15 as my front end for my web application. Now I am trying to login and below is my front end piece of code for it. I am passing details in userAccount and this function is called from a component. I am successful in getting login details inside below function.

```
authenticate(userAccount) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(userAccount.username + ':' + userAccount.password));
    headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    return this.http.get('/authenticate', {headers: headers}).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

My spring security file contains following information.

```
@Autowired
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
@Configuration
public static class UserSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception{
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/front-end/**");
    }
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
 http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/**","/login")
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/angular2/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/node_modules/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").access("hasRole('" + ROLE_EMPLOYEE + "') or hasRole('" + ROLE_ADMIN + "') ")
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint()).accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                    .rememberMe().tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()).tokenValiditySeconds(REMEMBER_ME_TOKEN_EXPIRATION).and().csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
                    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);;

    }
```

Now, when i try to login using valid credentials, I am getting 'undefined' as my username on the backend inside customUserDetailsService. Because of which request will end as 401 unauthorized. Can somebody guide me what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem on angular side. btoa function returned wrong user name and password. rest everything was good.